# C/C++ predefine array with memory values

Tags: c++, c, memory

I want to make a predefinition of some array with data from specific memory location, but it just not working for some reason.

```
// Location of first byte in memory
#define MEMORY   0x7800

// Take a data from memory to array which will be containing the data
const uint8_t *MemArray[3] = { (const uint8_t *)MEMORY, 
                               (const uint8_t *)MEMORY+1, 
                               (const uint8_t *)MEMORY+3 };

// Now, I want to define some another array with values upper, but it not working
const uint8_t TargetArray[7] = { 1,2,3,4, 
                                 (const uint8_t)(*MemArray[0]), 
                                 (const uint8_t)(*MemArray[1]), 
                                 (const uint8_t)(*MemArray[2]) };
```

Anybody know how to do it?

Compiler gets a warning and error at **(const uint8_t)(*MemArray[i])** lines

Warning[Pe191]: type qualifier is meaningless on cast type D:..\Source\file.c

Error[Pe028]: expression must have a constant value D:..\Source\file.c

I'm using IAR compiler for 8051 core

Comment: "doesn't work" and "not working" is not a good description of your situation. Your errors might not be very relevant in this instance, but you should make a habit of including information.

Comment: What did you correct? Your question still says nothing about any errors you're seeing beyond "just not working". Did you get an error message? If so, include it in your question. I've reformatted your code so it can all be seen without side-scrolling.

Comment: Ok, I'm included them

Answer (score 3):

Initializer values must be compile-time constant. Thus, they can't depend on values read out of the memory, the compiler must be able to generate the initialized array.

You need to include actual code to set this up. Just do that first in `main()`, before the rest of your program.

Comment: Yeah, I do it right now with mem_cpy, but in this situation arrays should be static, I mean they should be in RAM memory, but I have a lack of it, so I want to keep the array as const. If there is no other way to do it, well ok, thanks anyway

Comment: @user3914764: It can't be static because the compiler doesn't know what the runtime value of position 0x00007802 will be.

Comment: Mm no, he knows, this is a special memory location for read only data, and it's working fine now, but as I said it better to make this array as const

Answer (score 0):

Are the addresses associated with a very slow device? Otherwise you can just have a const pointer point to that location and read out the values at will.

Something like this:

```
#define MEMORY 0x7800

const struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)){
    uint8_t foo;
    uint8_t bar;
    uint8_t __reserved;
    uint8_t baz;
} *mem = (const void *)MEMORY;
```

You can read the locations by `mem->foo` etc.

Note: The exact syntax for struct packing varies, used GCC's in this example.

Comment: I'm using IAR compiler and he don't know __attribute__ or __packed__ later I'll try to find some similar declarations